# IPad Camera Orientation issue

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios6, camera

I am implementing an Application Regarding to Camera Mode Functionality But App Run Only Landscape But the Camera Opens in Some part of the IPad Only Remaining is in Black.

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        camPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        camPicker.delegate = self;
        camPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:camPicker animated:YES];
```

For Orientations Fixed as

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}else
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

Comment: Till Not open The Camera in Full Screen!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set orientation as:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: The `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation...` method isn't used in iOS 6.x.